# How do I Detect if a file is outside of a directory tree?

Tags: php

I've created a basic page where people "sign up" to upload/delete files in their own isolated folder.
The uploading/deleting of files are secure, however I would also like to allow admins to "deny" files.

The code alone works, except if anyone changes the URL to somewhere else on the server, they can "deny" any file on the system putting it at risk. I am looking to create a system function of which detects if the file they are targeting exists anywhere in the directory tree.

*Here's the code that I am using of which I'd like to create a function that returns either true/false.*

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['deny'])) {
    $tree_start = "Uploads";
    $targeted_file = $_GET['deny'];
    $safe_to_delete = in_directory_tree($tree_start, $targeted_file); <-- Looking for this
    if( $safe_to_delete == false ) {die("This file does not exist in the directory tree");}
    rename($_GET['deny'], "./Uploads/@Denied/". basename($_GET['deny']) );
}
?>
```

My Directory tree:

```
.htaccess <-- Prevent downloading of the database
admin.php <-- Problematic file browser script
index.php <-- User File management script
Users.db  <-- Names and hashed passwords

Uploads: 
  [FILE] htaccess <-- Prevent script execution (layer 2).
  [DIR] @Accepted: Notes.png, Video.mp4, etc...
  [DIR] @Denied: Project.png, new_timetable.txt, etc...
  [DIR] Admin: Proj1.txt, Proj1.png, etc...
  [DIR] User1: Task1.txt, Task2.txt, etc...
  [DIR] User2: Video1.txt, date.txt, etc...
```

Comment: I would be initially very cautious of putting important data (filepath) in a `$_GET` query. This could probably be very easily listed through automatically

Answer (score 1):

give this code a try:

```
    function in_directory_tree($dir,$file_to_search){

    $filesList = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("uploads");
    $targetFile = "contact.php" ;
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filesList) as $file)
    {
        $contents = explode("\\",$file);
        if (in_array($targetFile, $contents))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code will load the directory and start searching recursively, if it reaches the end without finding the file it will return false, otherwise it will return true.
I used `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` as it will help us get inside directories to list them

Comment: An answer should not only provide code, but also explain *why* this is what the question asks and *how* it works.

Comment: @Polygnome, thanks for pointing that out, I missed it since I was copying the code from my server and thought I explained what it will do :)

Comment: Am I using this code wrong? Using the code (`in_directory_tree("Uploads", $targeted_file`) only seems to return true if it's in the same directory which seems to be doing the same thing as `file_exists("Uploads/$targeted_file")` would.

Comment: @SmilerRyan, it depends on how you wrote your function, the function `in_directory_tree()` must search inside the directories that are child of `uploads`, otherwise, yes it will be the same as `file_exists`

Comment: @RayA, I've used the function as-is (inserting it before the check, with the same name) and have it set it up the same way as the example (searching in uploads/user for a file) and the output of this returns false.

Comment: @SmilerRyan, check the code now, I guess it should return true once it finds the file, keep in mind you might need to change the slash operator

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by preventing path traversal instead of checking if the file exists in this folder. This code works for me (returns true only when a file in /uploads exists (and blocks going back using C:/, ../, etc), and returns true only when the file does exist. Here is the finished code:

```
<?php

// Code used for the deny button:
// <button onclick="location.href='?deny=SmilerRyan/Project.png';">Deny</button>

if(isset($_GET['deny'])) {

$userpath = $_GET['deny'];
$basepath = 'Uploads/';
$realBase = realpath($basepath);
$userpath = $basepath . $userpath;
$realUserPath = realpath($userpath);
if ($realUserPath === false || strpos($realUserPath, $realBase) !== 0) {
    die("Invalid path - Possible Attack Blocked");
} else {
    rename($userpath, "./Uploads/@Denied/" . basename($userpath) );
}

}
?>
```

Comment: The great thing about your question is the fact you found the solution and never hesitate to share it, Thanks for taking time and initiative to share with us, just a small advise, avoid using get, replace it with POST or any other way to keep yourself as secure as possible.